# Angular `<router-outlet>` displays template twice

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm using angular4 and trying to create a router link. The router link works but displays the template twice.
[image: duplicate component]

Below is my code in the component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <h1>Contacts App</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a [routerLink]="['/facebook/top']">Contact List</a></li>
    </ul>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
    ){ }

    gotoDetail(): void {
        this.router.navigate(['facebook/top']);
    }
}
```

my routes:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppComponent },
  { path: 'facebook/top',  component: CommentComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your default route points to `AppComponent`, so your route is rendering the `AppComponent` inside the `AppComponent`.

Create a `DashboardComponent` or `HomeComponent` for this. And then do:

```
{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
```

**Update 1:**

As @GünterZöchbauer mentioned, we should add `pathMatch: 'full'` for *"an empty path route with no children"*.

So we can go with the `AppComponent` approach *(check [Günter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43522096/4962329))*:

```
{ path: '', component: AppComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Or, the `DashboardComponent` approach as I stated above in my answer.

Comment: @kevinabraham No problem, Always glad to be helpful!

Comment: or use redirect to path

Comment: hey! I've got the same issue and tried to creat separate component for that:
      { path: '', component: AppComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
but still is duplicated

Answer (score 17):

**Why is this happening?**

1) In your application entry point, most likely `main.ts`, one can read this line:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

This tells angular to bootstrap the module *AppModule*

2) In *AppModule*, one can find this line:

```
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
```

This tells angular to bootstrap the component *AppComponent*. This is why you see the first **Contacts App** part, because the html template of the AppComponent is:

```
<h1>Contacts App</h1>
<ul>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/facebook/top']">Contact List</a></li>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

3) However, the template of your *AppComponent* also contains `<router-outlet>`. The router reads the routes configuration, accordingly creates a new instance of *AppComponent* and inject it right after the element `<router-outlet>`. This is why you see the second **Contacts App** part.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Michael, made it clearer as to what was going wrong

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: this is great! should be melded with the marked answer

Answer (score 8):

If you have an empty path route with no children, use `pathMatch: 'full'`

instead of

```
{ path: '', component: AppComponent },
```

use

```
{ path: '', component: AppComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
```

and what @SrAxi said.

Comment: With your permission, I added this to my answer in order to make it more complete, obviusly I tagged you and mentioned you.

Comment: @SrAxi sure :) .

Answer (score 3):

In your app-routing.module.ts file try to use:

```
{path: '' , redirectTo: 'AppComponent', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

instead of:

```
{ path: '', component: AppComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
```