# Dynamically loaded module causes Angular `<router-outlet>` to display twice

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-module

The solution to this is somewhere in [Angular `<router-outlet>` displays template twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521410/angular-router-outlet-displays-template-twice), but I'm unable to apply it because my example differs due to dynamically loaded modules.

I have a nested `<router-outlet>` setup;

- `localhost:4200/login` renders the `LoginComponent` in the top-level component, `AppComponent`
- `localhost:4200/main` renders the `MainComponent` in the top-level component, `AppComponent`

  - `MainComponent` contains a `<router-outlet>` in which `LeafComponent` is rendered.

The app-structure:

```
app.component.ts       <router-outlet>
components/
    login/
        login-component.ts
    main/
        main-module.ts
        main-component.ts       <router-outlet>
        components/
            leaf-component.ts
```

The following is taken from `app.module` and works *iff* `main-module` is *not* dynamically loaded. I.e. it only works if `main-component` is instantiated.

```js
const redirectUnauthorizedToLogin = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['/login']);
const redirectLoggedInToMain = () => redirectLoggedInTo(['/main']);

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: LoginComponent,
    canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard],
    data: { authGuardPipe: redirectLoggedInToMain },
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard],
    data: { authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToLogin },
    children: [

      { path: '', redirectTo: '/main', pathMatch: 'full' },
      // ----> Render leaf-component in main-component <router-outlet>
      {
        path: 'main',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: LeafComponent,
      },

    ],
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];
```

This works. But when dynamically loading the `LeafModule`, the `MainComponent` is rendered twice. I.e. it does not work when `main-module` is dynamically loaded and **then** `main-component` is instantiated.

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: LoginComponent,
    canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard],
    data: { authGuardPipe: redirectLoggedInToMain },
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard],
    data: { authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToLogin },
    children: [

      { path: '', redirectTo: '/main', pathMatch: 'full' },
      // ----> Dynamically load leaf-module
      // ----> Render leaf-component in main-component <router-outlet>
      {
        path: 'main',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        loadChildren: () => import('./components/main/components/leaf/leaf.module').then(m => m.LeafModule)
      },

    ],
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];
```

---

**Solution Details**

@inge-olaisen's suggestion solved my problem but I wanted to add some detail here for completeness.

My mistake was not appreciating that a dynamically loaded module MUST(?) have a route, even if that route just loads the default modulel:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LeafComponent } from './leaf.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LeafComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LeafRoutingModule { }
```

This still seems a little redundant since because there are no routes. But because I want to lazy load the component, I must add them.

I also used separate routing modules which did make things clearer.

Finally, [Angular 8 | Nested Routing with Multiple RouterOutlet using loadChildren having own Router Modules Example Application](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-nested-routing-with-multiple-routeroutlet-using-loadchildren-having-own-router-modules-example-application/), is probably the simplest and most complete example of *nested routing with lazy-loaded modules* out there (IMO). It also uses a recent version of Angular and thus the new load `loadChildren: () => import('./foo.module').then(m => m.FooModule)` syntax. It also has a [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-routing-with-modules-with-bootstrap?embed=1&file=src/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're missing some key information. Does the leaf.module have it's own router module? A leaf-routing.module.ts for instance. That routing module should in turn have pathmatching for '' which loads the LeafComponent.

If you don't have that routing module, the module doesn't know which route to look for and I'm assuming the problem is the same as the person you linked to had, but instead you're missing the '' path for the LeafRoutingModule.

Comment: Correct, and thanks for you answer; there is no routing module for `leaf-module`, however, I have defined an [entry component](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components) for that module. I assumed this provides an entry point for the module when lazy loaded.