# Simple app routing is not working - Angular

Tags: angular

I have created one simple project and added it with one component. Added the component in routing configuration and app-module.

Whenever I navigate to another component, it stayed with the same component.

let me know, what I am doing wrong here

**Stackblitz** demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fgzrqh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-preference%2Fuser-preference.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

in your app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [`RouterOutlet`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) to the template to enable the path config.

Template

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/settings']">
    Click to go 'UserPreferenceComponent'
</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

If you see the `app.component.html` rendered twice, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43521410/6513921) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

you can also work more than one router outlet like that
Each outlet can have a unique name, determined by the optional name attribute. The name cannot be set or changed dynamically. If not set, default value is "primary"

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name='left'></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name='right'></router-outlet>
```

Named outlets can be the targets of secondary routes. The Route object for a secondary route has an outlet property to identify the target outlet:

```
{path: <base-path>, component: <component>, outlet: <target_outlet_name>}
```

Using named outlets and secondary routes, you can target multiple outlets in the same RouterLink directive