# Angular <router-outet> is displaying the parent twice

Tags: angular, typescript, redirect, routes

I have a parent component (**RemoteMpnitoringOverviewComponent**) and a child (**FilterIncidentsComponent**) that is a modal, but I don't know why the parent component is displayed twice. I have tried the solution from [Angular `<router-outlet>` displays template twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521410/angular-router-outlet-displays-template-twice), but without any result.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [MsalGuard],
    canActivateChild: [MsalGuard],
    component: RemoteMonitoringOverviewComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '', component: RemoteMonitoringOverviewComponent, children: [
          { path: 'filter', component: FilterIncidentsComponent },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
];
```

Comment: We need more information, maybe you should add the code insite your app.component.html and  remotemonitoringoverview.component.html so we can see what's being displayed

Answer (score 0):

In the first nested level, you should just use "redirectTo" instead of assigning the component twice. Like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [MsalGuard],
    canActivateChild: [MsalGuard],
    component: RemoteMonitoringOverviewComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '', redirectTo: 'filter', pathMatch: 'full', children: [
          { path: 'filter', component: FilterIncidentsComponent },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
];
```